# how to get num_rows() on a non-object in CI

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

so i'd like to get the response from my model:

```
function get_list_sales_kit(){
        $brispot = $this->load->database('brispot',TRUE);
        $brispot->select('id,title,imgurl,description');
        $qrydata = $brispot->get('saleskit');
        $brispot->close();
        return $qrydata->result();
    }
```

and this is the function to call that model:

```
function salesKit2($request){
    $result = new stdClass;
    $user='';
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('libs_bearer');
    $CI->load->library('libs_brispot');
    $CI->load->model('service_model');
        $datapost = json_decode($request);
        if(isset($datapost->user)){
            $user = substr('00000000'.$CI->security->xss_clean(trim($datapost->user)),-8);
            if($CI->libs_bearer->cekToken($user)==true){
                $getdata = $CI->service_model->get_list_sales_kit();
                if($getdata->num_rows()>0){
                    $result->responseCode='00';
                    $result->responseDesc='Inquiry berhasil.';
                    $result->responseData=$getdata->result();
                }

}
```

but i got eror result like fatal eror Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object.
i confused how to call non object on num_row, or is there anything to replace num_row to get the response?

Comment: Cant you just use `if (count($getdata) > 0) {`? Your also already calling `return $qrydata->result();` so `$result->responseData=$getdata->result();` most likely wont work.

Comment: `if( $qrydata->num_rows() > 0 ) return $qrydata->result(); return FALSE;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to return the result from your `get_list_sales_kit()` function the only way to get the number of rows is to `count($getdata)` as Lawrence said in the comments.

With that being said, I sometimes return the database object itself like so:

```
function get_list_sales_kit(){
        $brispot = $this->load->database('brispot',TRUE);
        $brispot->select('id,title,imgurl,description');
        $qrydata = $brispot->get('saleskit');
        $brispot->close();
        return $qrydata; // this line changed
    }
```

as such you can run any CI database functions on it like `row()` `result()` `num_rows()` and so on. Nothing has to be changed in the second code snippet as for some reason you are already accessing the `result()` object even though you are returning it in the first function.

Note: I'm not sure if `close()` will affect the objects being called after the fact. Why are you closing the database after doing one thing?

Comment: i think yours is true
my fault get the data through result twice